# Scrolling row disappear behind another row with transparent background

Tags: html, css, material-design

I'm trying to get a row that when it scrolls up it disappears behind a row filled with text. The issue I have is the background is patterned so I can't just color the background of the text row and have the other row scroll below it like it would usually. Is there any way I can make the scrolling row just disappear when it reaches the row above?

```css
#main-container {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
}

#title-text {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "CallingAngelsPersonalUse";
  text-shadow: 4px 6px 12px #ooo;
}

#date-text {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Strawberry_Whipped_Cream";
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 6px #fff;
}

#title-text-small {
  background:inherit;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  font-size: 12vw;
  color: black;
  font-family: "CallingAngelsPersonalUse";
  text-shadow: 4px 6px 12px #fff;
}

#date-text-small {
  background:inherit;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Strawberry_Whipped_Cream";
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 6px #fff;
}

#title-row-small {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background:inherit;
  position: fixed;
}

#title-container-small {
  background:inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  #card-row {
    top: 180px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: -180px;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
  #card-container {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){
  #card-row {
    top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
  #card-row {
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

#modal-title {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: "Strawberry_Whipped_Cream";
  font-size: 4vw;
}

#modal-text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: "OpenSans-Regular";
  font-size: 4vw;
}

#card-title {
  font-family: "OpenSans-Regular";
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -20px;
}

#button {
  font-family: "OpenSans-Regular";
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

#map-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#map-image-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: "OpenSans-Regular";
}

#confetti-link {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: "OpenSans-Regular";
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  max-height:80%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 99%;
  margin: auto;
}

.modal-content {
  height:90%;
  padding:0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-footer {
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<div id="main-container" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container center">
      <div class="show-on-medium-and-up hide-on-small-only">
        <p id="title-text">Scott and Viki</p>
        <p id="date-text">23/06/18</p>
        <a id="button" class="black waves-effect waves-light btn z-depth-3" href="mailto:scottandviki@gmail.com?subject=Wedding%20R.S.V.P"><i class="material-icons right">email</i>R.S.V.P</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="title-row-small" class="row">
    <div class="container center">
      <div id="title-container-small" class="col s12 show-on-small-only hide-on-med-and-up">
        <p id="title-text-small">Scott and Viki</p>
        <p id="date-text-small">23/06/18</p>
        <a id="button" class="black waves-effect waves-light btn z-depth-3" href="mailto:scottandviki@gmail.com?subject=Wedding%20R.S.V.P"><i class="material-icons right">email</i>R.S.V.P</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Agenda Card -->
  <div id="card-row" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#agenda-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Agenda</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Map Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#map-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Map</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Confetti Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#confetti-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Confetti</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Hotels & Taxi's Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#hotel-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Hotels & Taxi's</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Children Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#children-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Children</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Camping Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#camping-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Camping</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible? Currently, when i scroll you can see the cards behind the text which doesn't look great.

Here is an image of the site so far: [image]

Comment: You could put the rows you want to move in a separate container, and set the css overflow property of that container to 'hidden', 'scroll' or 'auto'. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow Regrettably the code in your question is incomplete, so I cannot provide an example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hi i tried adding a container around the card row and then adding the overflow property, then changing it to hidden scroll and auto but could still see it behind the text. Ive added the complete html minus the modals

Comment: You haven't read this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Answering questions is much harder when the code included is not minimal, complete and verifiable. Your chance of getting a good answer is much greater when you provide a working example of your problem. (my typing is a bit off)

Comment: i cant quite get the snippet to work as the code is only supposed to scroll for mobile but i cant get the snippet screen that small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I came up with another solution*

You have to set `overflow:hidden` and `height:100%` to `#main-container` and then apply `overflow:scroll` to the `#card-row`

**[Working Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/zaa0xb1j/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a background to your fixed positioned  `#card-row` div.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#title-row-small {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#card-row {
  top: 180px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: -180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<div id="main-container" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container center">
      <div class="show-on-medium-and-up hide-on-small-only">
        <p id="title-text">Scott and Viki</p>
        <p id="date-text">23/06/18</p>
        <a id="button" class="black waves-effect waves-light btn z-depth-3" href="mailto:scottandviki@gmail.com?subject=Wedding%20R.S.V.P"><i class="material-icons right">email</i>R.S.V.P</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="title-row-small" class="row">
    <div class="container center">
      <div id="title-container-small" class="col s12 show-on-small-only hide-on-med-and-up">
        <p id="title-text-small">Scott and Viki</p>
        <p id="date-text-small">23/06/18</p>
        <a id="button" class="black waves-effect waves-light btn z-depth-3" href="mailto:scottandviki@gmail.com?subject=Wedding%20R.S.V.P"><i class="material-icons right">email</i>R.S.V.P</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Agenda Card -->
  <div id="card-row" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#agenda-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Agenda</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Map Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#map-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Map</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Confetti Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#confetti-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Confetti</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Hotels & Taxi's Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#hotel-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Hotels & Taxi's</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Children Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#children-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Children</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Camping Card -->
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 xl4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#camping-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="z-depth-4">
            <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Camping</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this has put the cards above the text?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'd like the cards to go behind the text and also not be visble when they do.

Comment: @Wrumble as i understand i think you have to set a background color to the top row...see the updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work as the background is an image with a pattern. Thanks though.

Comment: but it would need to match the background perfectly though right? otherwise you would see the pattern not lining up

Comment: this feels like a hack, i cant see it working for a responsive page across mobile/tablet/desktop. maybe im missing waht your saying though